# I have written a code of mergeSort(from clrs book) but not getting an output

Tags: c, algorithm, mergesort

I have taken a reference from **clrs book of Introduction to Algorithms** of Merge Sort Algorithms and written a program in C language. Though I had check it manually by pen and paper the code seems to be correct then also I am not getting the right output.

The Output is shown below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

void merge(int array[], int start, int middle, int end) {
    int n1 = middle - start + 1;
    int n2 = end - start;
    int i;
    int leftarray[n1 + 1], rightarray[n2 + 1];
    for (i = 0; i < n1; i++) {
        leftarray[i] = array[start + i];
    }
    for (int j = 0; i < n2; i++) {
        rightarray[j] = array[middle + j + 1];
    }
    leftarray[n1 + 1] = 1000000;
    rightarray[n2 + 1] = 1000000;
    
    int k, j = 0;
    i = 0;
    for (k = start; k <= end; k++) {
        if (leftarray[i] > rightarray[j]) {
            array[k] = rightarray[j];
            j++;
        } else {
            array[k] = leftarray[i];
            i++;
        }
    }
}

void mergeSort(int array[], int start, int end) {
    if (start < end) {
        int middle = (start + end) / 2;
        mergeSort(array, start, middle);
        mergeSort(array, middle + 1, end);
        merge(array, start, middle, end);   
    }
}

void sorting(int array[], int length) {
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        printf("%d ", array[i]);
    }   
}

int main() {
    int noOfelements;
    scanf("%d", &noOfelements);
    int array[noOfelements];
    for (int i = 0; i < noOfelements; i++) {
        scanf("%d", &array[i]);
    }
    printf("Before Sorting: ");
    sorting(array, noOfelements);
    mergeSort(array, 0, noOfelements - 1);
    printf("After Sorting: ");
    sorting(array, noOfelements);
    return 0;   
}
```

Output of the Above Program:

```
5
5 4 3 2 1 
Before Sorting: 5 4 3 2 1 After Sorting: 2 0 5 0 32
```

Comment: Please do not post text as an image. Copy it directly as text into the question.

Comment: @Sameer Vhatkar You are not outputting anything for example after this statement printf("Before Sorting: ");

Comment: @VladfromMoscow The `sorting` function should really be called `printArray`.

Comment: `leftarray[n1+1]  = 1000000;` um... *what* ?? Besides making no sense, those lines also invoke *undefined behavior*. The VLA is only `n1+1` in size, so indexible only to `n1`. Likewise with `rightarray[n2+1]  = 1000000;` and `n2`.

Answer (score 1):

Although the book **Introduction to Algorithms** by *Thomas H Cormen, Charles E Leiserson , Ronald L Rivest, and Clifford Stein*, is considered an excellent textbook, the algorithm you implemented has several shortcomings:

- it uses the concept of sentinel values, values set at the end of the arrays to be merged, supposedly larger than any existing values, to hopefully simplify the merging process. In reality, there are no such values as if there were any, why should they not appear in the arrays as regular values?
- it uses `end` as the index of the last element in the array: it would be much simpler to use `end` as the index of the first element beyond the array, thus removing the need for confusing `+1` / `-1` adjustments and allowing for empty arrays.
- you use `int middle = (start + end) / 2;` which could overflow for large values of `start` and `end`, although other parts of your implementation would fail if you try and sort such a huge array. Still it is safer to write `int middle = start + (end - start) / 2;`

Your code fails because you set the sentinel values one position too far. You should write:

```
  leftarray[n1] = 1000000;
  rightarray[n2] = 1000000;
```

Here is a better approach:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void merge(int array[], int start, int middle, int end) {
    int n1 = middle - start;
    int i, j, k;

    // save the elements from the left half, no need to save the right half
    int leftarray[n1];
    for (i = 0; i < n1; i++) {
        leftarray[i] = array[start + i];
    }
    
    for (i = 0, j = middle, k = start; i < n1; k++) {
        if (j >= end || leftarray[i] <= array[j]) {
            array[k] = leftarray[i];
            i++;
        } else {
            array[k] = array[j];
            j++;
        }
    }
}

void mergeSort(int array[], int start, int end) {
    if (end - start >= 2) {
        int middle = start + (end - start) / 2;
        if (middle - start > 100000) {
            // avoid stack overflow: allocate at most 100k ints for `leftarray`
            middle = start + 100000;
        }
        mergeSort(array, start, middle);
        mergeSort(array, middle, end);
        merge(array, start, middle, end);   
    }
}

void print_array(const char *prefix, const int array[], int length) {
    printf("%s:", prefix);
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        printf(" %d", array[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}

int main() {
    int noOfelements;
    if (scanf("%d", &noOfelements) != 1 || noOfelements < 0)
        return 1;
    int array[noOfelements];
    for (int i = 0; i < noOfelements; i++) {
        if (scanf("%d", &array[i]) != 1)
            return 1;
    }
    print_array("Before Sorting", array, noOfelements);
    mergeSort(array, 0, noOfelements);
    print_array("After Sorting", array, noOfelements);
    return 0;   
}
```

Comment: `int middle = (start + end)/2` - changing this to `size_t middle = (start + end)/2` should be enough. On a 32 bit system, overflow could only occur if start+end > 2^32, which implies at least `end` > 2^31 (2GB). This could only happen if sorting an array of bytes greater than 2GB in size, which is not likely.  On a 64 bit system, size_t would exceed the size of memory.

Comment: @rcgldr: the problem is not with the type of `middle`, but with that of `start` and `end`. They are `int` variables, so indeed the problem occurs for arrays with more than 1 billion or so items, which is quite feasible on 64-bit systems, where type `int` still only has 31 value bits. This bug is a classic, it was even present in the [Python zlib extension module allowing for arbitrary code execution](https://securitytracker.com/id?1019823)

Comment: I should have explained that I was suggesting using size_t on start and end as well. On a 64 bit system, they would be 64 bit unsigned integers.